# Upload video to Amazon S3 via iOS

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload videos to Amazon S3 via my iOS app. I'm struggling to use the documentation provided by AWS.

Firstly, what should the contentType be if I want to upload .mov videos to S3? I can't seem to find any documentation of the format of content I can upload.

Secondly, how do I pass my .mov video as a Data() object?

```
func uploadData() {

   let data: Data = Data() // Data to be uploaded

   let expression = AWSS3TransferUtilityMultiPartUploadExpression()
      expression.progressBlock = {(task, progress) in
         DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
           // Do something e.g. Update a progress bar.
        })
   }

   var completionHandler: AWSS3TransferUtilityMultiPartUploadCompletionHandlerBlock
   completionHandler = { (task, error) -> Void in
      DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
         // Do something e.g. Alert a user for transfer completion.
         // On failed uploads, `error` contains the error object.
      })
   }

   let transferUtility = AWSS3TransferUtility.default()

   transferUtility.uploadUsingMultiPart(data:data,
        bucket: "YourBucket",
        key: "YourFileName",
        contentType: "text/plain",
        expression: expression,
        completionHandler: completionHandler).continueWith {
           (task) -> AnyObject! in
               if let error = task.error {
                  print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
               }

               if let _ = task.result {
                  // Do something with uploadTask.
               }
               return nil;
       }
}
```

Comment: video/quicktime

Answer (score 0):

Try This Function For Upload Image/Video in AWS

```
public struct AWSConstant {
    static let COGNITO_POOL_ID = "us-west-2:4918c1f8-d173-4668-8891-d6892a147259"
    static let BUCKET_NAME = "spinach-cafe/main-image"
    static let baseUrl = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/"
}

func uploadVideoToAmazon(currentFileName: String, videoFileURL: URL, contentType: String = "image/jpeg", _ bucket: String?, progressBlock: @escaping (Float) -> () = { _ in }, callBack: @escaping (_ url: String) -> Void?, failedBlock: @escaping (Error?) -> () = { _ in }) {

    let myIdentityPoolId = AWSConstant.COGNITO_POOL_ID

    let credentialsProvider: AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: .USWest2, identityPoolId: myIdentityPoolId)

    let endpoint = AWSEndpoint.init(region: .USWest2, service: .S3, useUnsafeURL: false)
    let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration.init(region: .USWest2, endpoint: endpoint, credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)
    AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration

    var S3BucketName = AWSConstant.BUCKET_NAME
    if let bucketName = bucket {
        S3BucketName = bucketName
    }

    let remoteName = currentFileName

    let uploadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest()
    uploadRequest?.body = videoFileURL
    uploadRequest?.key = remoteName
    uploadRequest?.bucket = S3BucketName
    uploadRequest?.contentType = contentType
    uploadRequest?.acl = .publicRead

    uploadRequests.append(uploadRequest)

    uploadRequest?.uploadProgress = { bytesSent, totalBytesSent, totalBytesExpectedToSend in
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            print("\(totalBytesSent)/\(totalBytesExpectedToSend)")
        })
    }

    let transferManager = AWSS3TransferManager.default()

    // Perform file upload


    transferManager.upload(uploadRequest!).continueWith(block: { task -> Any? in

        if let error = task.error {
            print("Upload failed with error: (\(error.localizedDescription))")
        }

        if task.result != nil {
            let stringURL = "\(AWSConstant.baseUrl)\(S3BucketName)/\(currentFileName)"

            print("Uploaded to:\n\(stringURL)")

            // Remove locally stored file
            DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                callBack(stringURL)
            }

        }
        else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                failedBlock(task.error)
            }
            print("Unexpected empty result.")
        }
        return nil
    })
}
```